# opencv-python can not find the xfeatures2d module

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am using version 3.4.0 of *opencv-python* and have also installed the *contrib* package. I have followed opencv installation from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/).

I am using macOS. However when I run python inside `/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` , it is able to find the`xfeatures2d` module.

Comment: do you have opencv installed with the [contrib_module](http://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib) (either from source or [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python)) ?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed the opencv-contrib-python package at version 3.4.0.12 using pip

Comment: hmmm, hard to tell, maybe the Python binding's didn't get compiled with this module for some reason ? What do you get if you run `otool -L $(locate cv2.so)` ? (is the xfeatures2d dylib linked against the python library ?)

Comment: actually, reading again, it sounds like `/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` isn't added to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Can you double check this too: `echo $PYTHONPATH`. If that folder isn't added to `PYTHONPATH` you may need to add it like so: `PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH". Bare in mind this setting will go away if you reboot unless you add this command in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` (whichever you prefer using)

Comment: Okay thanks! My PYTHONPATH variable was somehow wrongly named as "/usr/local/opt/opencv3/ ..." changed it to "/usr/local/opt/opencv/ ..."

Comment: I'll add that note as an answer so it can be marked and easily found by others with the same issue in the future. I recommend appending to `PYTHONPATH` instead of replacing, just to avoid breaking other modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ isn't added to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

You can append the path by adding this line in ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile:

```
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

You'll need to open a new Terminal session for that to kick in (or run `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bash_profile` depending on which file you chose to use)